# Как отменить require_once в родительском functions.php?

Tags: php, wordpress

Всем доброго. В родительской теме в `functions.php` есть несколько `require_once(......);`. Как в `functions.php` дочерней темы отменить 1 или несколько `require_once()`, чтоб вместо них выбрать другие файлы (в дочерней теме)?

Comment: Никак. Это конструкция языка, на которую невозможно повлиять, по крайней мере, без дерегистрации нативного враппера для файловых url. В чем проблема, в объявленных функциях?

Comment: В том, что в functions.php родительской темы нет никаких функций. Только несолько require_once(....script.php). Если в дочерней functions.php  написать функцию из script.php то ничего работать не будет

Comment: Я правильно понял, что в этом случае надо не отменять, а корректировать? Можете привести полный пример?

Answer (score 2):

*Ответ из комментариев [Etki](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/16095/etki)*

Никак. Это конструкция языка, на которую невозможно повлиять, по крайней мере, без дерегистрации нативного враппера для файловых url.